# Is there a way to forbid a python function to use any variable except local ones?

Tags: python, scope

I am currently doing manual python code refactoring.

In order to be sure that I break nothing in the original code by forgetting to correct the instructions I enclose within functions, I want to be sure that the function can have no access to the global variables when I am testing them. What would be the right way to do this, except copying them in a separate module?

**Edit:**

Just to be clear: I am trying to convert my initial code into something like this:

```
def big_function(args):      
   def one_small_transformation(args):
       # No one else needs to see this transformation outside the function1

   def second_small_transformation(args):

   ...

   # Block of instructions chaining small transformations

# Other big functions and code making them work together
```

Sometimes I forget to correct the variable names in my small transforms and code inside small transformations call variables from the large block of instructions.

**Unittests:** The unittests for big_function are passed; errors pop in when I start editing the code after refactoring. On the current stage of the project, writing unittests for the small transformations looks like an overkill, because they will be completely re-written once the internal logic of the big_function is clear.

Comment: Removing all global variables from everywhere would be rather effective. And a good thing when you're refactoring code :P

Comment: Create another module and put your refactored functions there.  Each module has its own "global" namespace.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're doing here.  The best way to make sure you don't break anything is to write unit-tests rather than relying on strange hacks.  You can remove all globals (`func.func_globals.clear()` will do it IIRC), but that means that your function will have no access to globals (including other functions) and it will clear out your module's namespace which is unlikely what you want to do.

Comment: Note that technically every (module-level) function and class is accessed though a global variable. Surely you don't want to prevent *that*?

Comment: @mgilson: please see the edit for the unittest issues. Yes, I would like to keep the references to what I have imported and all the functions. An ideal solution for me would be a decorator that throws every instance of objects, but keeps everything else. What I would be looking is ideally an ``@limit_to_local_vars`` decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it advantages to first place all global variables into a singleton (global) object. This makes any use of the globals extremely obvious, aiding you down the road as you aim to reduce/eliminate them.

So, take global declarations in a module like

```
dir_root = "/example/rootdir"
debug_level = 3
```

and wrap them in a class with a single declared instance:

```
class GLOBALS:
  dir_root = ...
  debug_level = ...

Globals = GLOBALS()
```

Of course, existing references to the variables will have to be updated to use e.g. `Globals.dir_root` instead of `dir_root` directly.

The benefit of doing this is that it allows you to highlight the usage of globals while keeping application logic intact. This lets you do the refactoring in a more incremental manner that is less apt to introduce new logic errors. And as per your original question, you can be sure that any function that doesn't reference the `Globals` object explicitly is not using any global variables.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I was thinking there might be already a decorator to do this, but if I don't find it in the upcoming hours I will use your suggestion.